# ActiveMQ does not startup, throws SQLSyntaxException

Tags: java

I am in the process of migrating to ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and have a master-slave ActiveMQ setup.

This is my activemq.xml:

```
<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/activemq.properties</value>
    </property>      
</bean>

<!-- 
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker. 
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="${broker.name}" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true">


    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
              <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                <vmCursor />
              </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue="NotificationQueue" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="64mb" queuePrefetch="200" >
              <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                   For more information, see:

                   http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

              <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <vmQueueCursor/>
              </pendingQueuePolicy>
              -->
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue="ReportingQueue" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="10mb" queuePrefetch="200" >
             </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy> 

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#oracle-ds" useDatabaseLock="true" lockAcquireSleepInterval="10000" lockKeepAlivePeriod="10000" databaseLocker="#custom-locker" createTablesOnStartup="false"/>           
    </persistenceAdapter>


    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpaceAfterTimeout="30000">
        <!--<systemUsage>-->
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="128mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <!--<storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb" name="foo"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>-->
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="${connection.uri}"/>
    </transportConnectors>

</broker>

<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver.class.name}"/>
<property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
<property name="initialSize" value="${initialSize}"/>
<property name="minIdle" value="${minIdle}"/>
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${defaultAutoCommit}"/>
<property name="defaultReadOnly" value="${defaultReadOnly}"/>
<property name="maxActive" value="${maxActive}"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="${maxIdle}"/>
<property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="${poolPreparedStatements}"/>
<property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="${maxOpenPreparedStatements}"/>
<property name="maxWait" value="${maxWait}"/>
<property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="${numTestsPerEvictionRun}"/>
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="${testOnBorrow}"/>
<property name="testOnReturn" value="${testOnReturn}"/>
<property name="testWhileIdle" value="${testWhileIdle}"/>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="${validationQuery}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="custom-locker" class="com.symantec.cda.activemq.failover.AMQCustomFailover">
    <property name="lockKeepAlivePeriod" value="10000" />
</bean>

<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

On starting both master and slave on CLI, I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "XID": invalid identifier

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:785)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:860)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3381)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3425)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1490)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter.doRecoverPreparedOps(DefaultJDBCAdapter.java:957)
at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter.recover(JDBCPersistenceAdapter.java:728)
at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.recover(JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java:160)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.start(TransactionBroker.java:97)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService$5.start(BrokerService.java:2078)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:636)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:617)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:553)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:65)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:125)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:101)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (master, ID:symc-trustgateway-phy-be-51497-1366373603849-0:1). Reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to recover from: org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore@5e0eb724. Reason: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "XID": invalid identifier

I changed my activemq.xml to have the DB details hardcoded in it (rather than being referred to from activemq.properties file). So the dataSource attribute now points to this:

```
<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.141.148.225:1521:CDAQA3"/>
    <property name="username" value="cdaapps"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${initialSize}"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="${minIdle}"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${defaultAutoCommit}"/>
    <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="${defaultReadOnly}"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="${maxActive}"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${maxIdle}"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="${poolPreparedStatements}"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="${maxOpenPreparedStatements}"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="${maxWait}"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="${numTestsPerEvictionRun}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${testOnBorrow}"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="${testOnReturn}"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${testWhileIdle}"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${validationQuery}"/>
</bean>
```

Still the same exception occurs.

Comment: This is my activemq.properties file from where DB details are picked up.

broker.name=master

database.driver.class.name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.141.148.225:1521:CDAQA3
database.username=cdaapps
database.password=password

Comment: check if you can access the DB host from both master node and slave node

Comment: The DB can be accessed from both machines. Checked the connectivity to both DB's on command line.

Comment: Does activemq start if you start master / slave separately?

Comment: No, it does not start if master and slave are started separately.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with master/ slave configuration. You have to check single configuration first

Comment: I changed my activemq.xml to have the DB details hardcoded in it (rather than being referred to from activemq.properties file). So the dataSource attribute now points to what is shown in the question modified as above. However the same exception still occurs.

Comment: It worked now after doing a clean installation and startup.

Answer (score 1):

Below sql should take care of above exception while migration to ActiveMQ 5.8.0

```
ALTER TABLE ACTIVEMQ_MSGS Add  XID VARCHAR(250);
CREATE INDEX ACTIVEMQ_MSGS_XIDX ON ACTIVEMQ_MSGS (XID);
ALTER TABLE ACTIVEMQ_ACKS add  XID VARCHAR(250);
CREATE INDEX ACTIVEMQ_ACKS_XIDX ON ACTIVEMQ_ACKS (XID);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry, could have been more descriptive. Updated. Thanks @Jeen